# How to hide first element in div if its anchor

Tags: html, css

How can i hide anchor element inside div with class=grid-container. I only need to hide if first element is anchor a otherwise i dont need to hide.

I used below css but it hides all elements in div

```
.grid-container > a:first-of-type {
  display: none; 
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try [:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child).

```
.grid-container > a:first-child {
  display: none; 
}
```